# Generate Input Field Value From Select Date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

this : http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/ByTtp/

So I want to generate the input field value birhtday option is selected. I make javascript, but confused generate month and year.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#pelajar_tglahir_3i option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $("#pelajar_code").val();
    }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#pelajar_tglahir_3i").live("change", function() {
        $("#pelajar_code").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });

});
```

Example When select birthday is `1 March 1990` and input field value is `1March1990`..

Comment: as a side note: you really shouldn't be using .live() it is a bad function to use and even the jQuery team suggest in older versions where .on is not available to use .delegate over .live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way is just concat the values..like this on the `on()` method

```
var dateStr=$("#pelajar_tglahir_3i").val()+$("#pelajar_tglahir_2i").find("option:selected").text()+$("#pelajar_tglahir_1i").val();
$("#pelajar_code").val(dateStr);
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByTtp/4/)..you may need to do some validation though..